# Glade3 C Programming Buttons

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I'm very unaware of how the syntax goes for GTK+Glade3 programming.
But for now I'm trying to experiment and making a simple program that changes text when I click a button

```
void on_CLICK_clicked (GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *text = lookup_widget(GTK_WIDGET(button), "entry1");
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_WIDGET(text), "Hello");
}
```

I have these alarming errors that I don't know how to solve:

> implicit declaration of function 'lookup_widget' [which also explains the undefined reference to 'lookup_widget']
>
> passing argument 1 of gtk_entry_set_text' from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lookup_widget()` was only used in Glade 2's generated code. Glade 2 used to generate a file, `support.c`, that contained that function and other ones. This is not used anymore. You can now specify the entry widget as the user data parameter when you connect the `clicked` signal in Glade 3, so you can do the following:

```
void on_CLICK_clicked (GtkButton *button, GtkEntry *text)
{
    gtk_entry_set_text(text, "Hello");
}
```

The second warning was caused by you casting `text` to a `GtkWidget *` and then passing it to `gtk_entry_set_text()` which expects a `GtkEntry *`. The proper syntax would have been `GTK_ENTRY(text)`, but you don't need to do that anymore since you already have a `GtkEntry *` pointer in the code I wrote above.

Comment: Thank you! U hadn't realized that I could do that.